# GetCustomAttributes for an enum value return an empty Array

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm currently working on upgrading a windows 8.1 universal app to a windows 10 UWP app. There is a part of code that was working perfectly before that doesn't work anymore in my Windows 10 UWP app.

I have an enum that looks like this :

```
public enum EStaticFile
{
    [StringValue("Path of a file")]
    CONFIG_FILE_1,    

    [StringValue("Path of a file")]
    CONFIG_FILE_2
}
```

When I try to get the attribute for any of the enum values, it always returns an empty array. I use the following code :

```
public static StringValue GetStringValueAttribute(this Enum aEnumValue)
{
    Type type = aEnumValue.GetType();

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetRuntimeField(aEnumValue.ToString());
    StringValue[] attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValue), false) as StringValue[];
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0];
    }

   return null;
}
```

GetCustomAttributes always returns an empty array, so attributes.Length is always 0, so the function returns null;

Has something changed in Windows 10 that prevent this from working?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't [reproduce this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FqUO3i).  Perhaps it's some other incompatibility like namespace misnaming or different version of .NET framework?

Comment: yeah, probably because .NetFiddle is not under windows 10 and it's a console application and not a UWP app... It was working before I ugraded from windows 8.1 :(

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: If you find bugs in Windows 10, please file them with the Windows Feedback app - there is a section for Developer Platform issues. I'll also pass this on.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT: I have been investigating a question asked earlier today (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049601/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-content-property-in-uwp), and am seeing an issue similar to this. The weird thing is that I can reproduce the issue in Debug, without "Compile with .NET native tool chain" selected. The call to `GetCustomAttributes()` returns an empty enumeration. The `CustomAttributes` property, which returns `CustomAttributeData` objects instead, shows the data as expected, but of course does not include the actual attribute objects. Bug? Or just doing it wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem.

My solution contains C++ projects, so I activated the .Net Native, like it was said in every tutorials I saw about migrating a Windows 8.1 app to a Windows 10 UWP app, which is ok, but doing so sets the property UseDotNetNativeToolChain to true, which causes the problem. To fix the problem, just set it to false everywhere in your faulty project file and it will start working again! And .Net Native still works!

Hope it helps someone!